# How to edit the TextField value, with the value is already pre defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a form that comes with some data from a country. By default, the data is read-only, if the user wants to change the value, click on the edit button.

The problem is that I am not able to edit the value in `TextInput`, by default, the value `value` is already pre defined. I try to edit the value through `onChange()`, but it doesn't work.

Everything I type does not appear in the Input field.

Here's my code, I put in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-water-muq69?file=/src/App.js

I'm using `TextField` from `react-material`.

[image: form]

Can someone help me to update that´s values? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others stated, the problem is that you need `onChange` and `value` to point at same value/variable in state.

As a step further, I would clean all these variables in state and use only one method to change the properties (if for example you have many fields and the code gets long enough)

```
  const changeField = (name, value) => {
    let newCountryInfo = [...countryInfo];
    newCountryInfo[0].data.Country[0][name] = value;
    setCountry(newCountryInfo);
  };
```

and in each `TextField` you add sth like the following depending on the field

```
  onChange={event => {
    changeField("name", event.target.value);
  }}
```

Check [this codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-cherry-9qsx0)

Comment: Thank you very much Apostolos, that's work perfectly for me!! Thanks for the tip on this method, it was very good, I hadn't thought about it.;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a React expert but it seems that the react component is overriding all the changes that are being typed. you can see it on the dev console, just delete the value="brazil" and try to type something, the value="brazil" will pop up back to the input tag.
I can suggest to replace the value by placeholder. In that way the user sill still see the old value, and will be able to type new one.

Comment: Hey Vlad, above has the answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: as i said, i'm no react expert. i knew there were a better solution than mine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use State property as a value

const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState("");

```
<TextField
className={classes.field}
disabled={disabledField}
label="Name"

value={countryName}

onChange={event => {
  setCountryName(event.target.value);
}}
variant="outlined"
InputLabelProps={{
  shrink: true
}}
/>
```

and inside **useState("")** , define initial value or predefined value.

Comment: Hey Pushparmar, the problem when I did that, the field came with empty value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
value={item.data.Country[0].name}
```

whatever you have set in `value` attribute will remain in that. So instead of passing your API response here pass a state value in it and update that state on the change of input value ( 2 way data binding ). It will solve the issue.

Changes you have to made:

```
const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState("");

onChange={event => {
  setCountryName(event.target.value);  // This will update the state
}}
value={countryName}  // updated state value is used here
```

Comment: Hey Mayank, the problem when I did that, the fiedl came with empty value

Comment: @vbernal for initial value use `defaultValue`